# InResharper 2016.2 MVC specific feature is not visible/working

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have updated my resharper version to 2016.2 from 2016.1 (on visual studio 2015),
Suddenly it stops showing some the very often used feature specific to MVC like, hint for add view(which doesn't exists) for a action method in a controller, it is not even highlighting a navigation link for a `return View();` 
Even very less information provided in documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Web_Development__ASP.NET_MVC.html)

Also it is not highlighting hint error message for missing View file for a action method in controller.

Any hint to solve this issue is appreciated in advance. Problem Image

[image: NotWorking]

Expected to work as below (taken from documentation url mentioned above):

[image: Working]

Comment: What MVC version do you use?

Comment: I am using MVC version 5.2.3

Comment: 2016.2 stopped support of pre-release bits of ASP.NET Core 1.0, but 5.2.3 should be fine. You better to file ticket in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues#newissue=25-1304062 and provide your project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @derigel :)